# Does HDD firmware write back corrected sector when reading bad but correctable sector?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, hardware-failure, ecc

I understand what is error correction and how it works, what I want to know is that when the firmware of the drive is reading data and chances upon a damaged sector that contains enough information to have it corrected, in addition to delivering the correct data to the OS, **does it also write back the correct data to that sector**?

Would it make sense to occasionally have the OS read the entire drive to hopefully prevent the accumulation of such errors over long periods of time? Since they would presumably be regularly corrected to avoid reaching the threshold of an actual fault.

One has to wonder if a perfectly healthy drive can have bad sectors due to uncontrollable external factors which would then make it untrustworthy. Which such a "scrub" can hopefully prevent.

For example:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/null bs=32M iflag=direct status="progress"
```

My understanding is that something similar is regularly done to RAID drives (or perhaps the RAID virtual block device?), through for different reasons.

Comment: *"does it also write back the correct data to that sector?"* -- For the controller that I did the firmware, no.  For a modern SATA HDD, I would guess `no` for an unconditional rewrite. First, that's added overhead that requires additional time to perform.  Secondly, there's no guarantee that what is still a *correctable* error can be turned into an *error-free* sector.  Worst case is that a rewrite makes the correctability worse, not better.  Of course the OS always has the option of performing a preventative action when a soft error occurs.

Comment: @sawdust that is interesting, thanks. I did not know the firmware reports soft errors to the OS, do you know how to access this information on linux? wouldn't there be utilities for profiling hdd sectors to identify ones such as you listed to blacklist just in case?

Answer (score 0):

> ... does it also write back the correct data to that sector?

For the controller that I did the firmware, no.
For a modern SATA HDD, I would guess no for an unconditional rewrite.

First, that's unexpected overhead for the read operation that would require additional time to perform (i.e. another revolution of the platter).

Second, the error could be transient, and may not occur on a subsequent read.  For such a case the rewrite would not be warranted.

Third, there's no guarantee that what is still a correctable error can be turned into an error-free sector.  Worst case is that a rewrite makes the correctability worse, not better.

Of course the OS always has the option of performing a preventative action when a soft error occurs.

---

A HDD could optionally offer a rewrite capability.
The [Seagate SCSI manual](https://www.seagate.com/files/staticfiles/support/docs/manual/Interface%20manuals/100293068j.pdf) does mention a "Recovered Data With ECC—Data Rewritten" sense code in Table 29, which is *"is for reference only, as not all drives covered by this manual support all of the codes listed."*

---

> ... do you know how to access this information on linux?

A soft read error is treated as a successful read, and the correction is apparently reported in the (more-detailed) sense data as a "recovered error".
As part of the kernel processing for **scsi_io_completion()** the [following code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/scsi/scsi_lib.c#L851) is relevant:

```
/*
 * Recovered errors need reporting, but they're always treated as
 * success, so fiddle the result code here.  For passthrough requests
 * we already took a copy of the original into sreq->result which
 * is what gets returned to the user
 */
if (sense_valid && (sshdr.sense_key == RECOVERED_ERROR)) {
    bool do_print = true;
    /*
     * if ATA PASS-THROUGH INFORMATION AVAILABLE [0x0, 0x1d]
     * skip print since caller wants ATA registers. Only occurs
     * on SCSI ATA PASS_THROUGH commands when CK_COND=1
     */
    if ((sshdr.asc == 0x0) && (sshdr.ascq == 0x1d))
        do_print = false;
    else if (req->rq_flags & RQF_QUIET)
        do_print = false;
    if (do_print)
        scsi_print_sense(cmd);
    result = 0;
    /* for passthrough, *blk_statp may be set */
    *blk_statp = BLK_STS_OK;
}
```

Bottom line: A recovered error (or soft read error) can be logged (i.e. `do_print` is true so **scsi_print_sense()** is called), but there are exceptions that cause this logging to be skipped.
Additionally SCSI logging can be voluminous and could affect I/O throughput, so the information stored is controlled by the SCSI logging level.

A bash shell script, [scsi_logging_level](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/scsi_logging_level.8.html), can be used to accesses/modify the Linux SCSI subsystem logging level.
More details of the SCSI log are in [SCSI logging feature](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/linuxonibm/com.ibm.linux.z.ldsg/ldsg_r_scsilog.html).

> wouldn't there be utilities for profiling hdd sectors to identify ones such as you listed to blacklist just in case?

I don't know.
The quickest way to scan a HDD is to use the built-in SMART tests.  The sectors are read only by the drive, and no data is transferred to the host to slow down the test.